# Specific designation for end-of-sentence intonation

Tags: intonation

I have a question about a certain type of intonation.  Let's use the following sentence as an example:

> "What would you like for dinner?" asked mom as I entered the kitchen.

When I read this sentence, I would read the *"What would you like for dinner?"* portion with normal pitch, but would read the *"asked mom as I entered the kitchen"* in a lower pitch.

I'm wondering if there is a designation/name for this specific type of intonation.

Comment: I'm a syntactician, so I don't know what a phonologist would say, but I call it "flatting" and it seems to be associated with backgrounded constituents, often presupposed, like restrictive relative clauses.

Comment: Oh, and flatting is not limited to the end of the sentence; presupposed material can occur anywhere in a sentence.